# Clear App Data Onclick- Android

Tags: android

I want to             clear my app's "data" on button                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              click.

```
 public void clearappdata(View view) {
```

Answer (score -1):

You can clear your SharedPreferences through:

```
prefs.edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: Why unnecessary use of Shared Preferences???

Comment: Don't you store app data in preferences?  Please do not down vote an answer unnecessarily.